# How to call a stored procedure in an if statement using pass through query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, pass-through

I am using MS Access VBA and a SQL Server stored procedure for my application. I have a form *frmUsers* which has a textbox *UserName*. It is bound to username of tblUsers. If a user updates it using a '@' in front of the textbox input value, it has to  clear some columns (`Password` and `Hash`) in the SQL table `tblUser`.

I had already created a stored procedure for it and also wrote some code under *UserName_AfterUpdate*. I felt I need to create a pass-through query to call a store procedure inside the `If` statement as shown below; but it is not working (not deleting values in the table and also not giving any error).

The stored procedure works by itself but when I tried to test it with application i.e. insert '@' in front of textbox, it doesn't delete two columns in the table. I am missing out something to bind between pass-through query and the textbox. Please help.

**MS Access** VBA

```vb
Private Sub UserName_AfterUpdate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim strFilter As String

    Dim DB As Database
    Set DB = CodeDb

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUsers", , , , , acDialog
    Set frm = Forms!frmUsers

    If frm.Tag Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "sp_ClearWebsitePwd"
        strFilter = strFilter & ", " & frm!UserID      

        If Left(UserName, 1) = "@" Then        

            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Connect = SQLConnectString
            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").sql = strFilter
        End If  
    End If
End Sub
```

**SQL Server** stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClearWebsitePwd] 
    @userID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    UPDATE tblUser
    SET tblUser.Password = NULL, tblUser.Hash = NULL
    WHERE UserID = @userID 
END
```

MS Access pass-through query *(qryClearWebsitePwd)*

```
sp_ClearWebsitePwd, 20226
```

Comment: I suppose that `Password` field is encrypted? Why would you even need it though, given you're (apparently) storing a `Hash`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I just gave some name for the table columns. I need to nullify two columns. keeping '@' in front meaning deactivating the user from the system/application.

Comment: Sorry but why not make an explicit **delete** feature for deleting records?

Comment: For future use. Meaning, we need users' information other than that two fields once '@' kept in front. Also, this is what my seniors wanted. i.e create store procedure. creating pass-through was my idea. I am not sure if I even need to create a pass-through query though.

Comment: Please clarify what fields and types are involved. Your prose says `UserName`, your code checks if the `@` is in front of `CustomerName`, and the only form field in the code is `UserID` - it's kinda confusing.

Comment: I apologize for confusion. I am beginner for SQL. username is nvarchar and userid is int. Since there wasn't username in tblUser (it is in tblUser_contact), I used userid in my update statement in SP.

Comment: So what's `CustomerName` doing there?

Comment: `CustomerName` is what I need to check in the form if user had entered @ infront of it or not. I think I have to use `CustomerName` in my SP instead of `CustomerID`. Also, don't I have to link my form design with the pass-through query `qryClearWebsitePwd`. As I mentioned, I am not sure how do I link my textbox with this pass-through query. Please advise

Comment: You realize that from the readers' point of view, `CustomerName` just pops up in the middle of your code from out of nowhere? Again, please [edit] your question to clarify what the pieces of the puzzle are and how they're connected. You mention you stick `@` in front of "a textbox", but we don't know what field that textbox is bound to, and it's not clear from your code, and it's not clear from your post. I'm voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*, answers can only be guesswork until you fix your post.

Comment: Your Procedure is named `UserName_AfterUpdate()` indicating that it's attached to a text box called `UserName` somewhere on your form. In your code, you're looking at a variable called `CustomerName` to see if the first character is an `@`. I'm willing to be that if you put `Option Explicit` as the very first line of your code module and try to compile, the VBE will tell you that `CustomerName` is an undeclared variable. ...

Comment: ... Once you get that sorted out, I'm pretty sure that [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42378050/2344413) has the right answer. You prepare your query (based on incorrect conditions at the moment), but never actually `.Execute` it.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, you do not [.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821728.aspx) your query so it does nothing. You only change its SQL and connection string properties.

Also, you do not need the comma separation or '@' prefix when calling the stored procedure. Remove the '@' user instruction from the form and just pass the integer. And if connection property never changes, there is no need to update it, so that line can be removed.

```vb
If frm.Tag Then
    strFilter = "sp_ClearWebsitePwd " & frm!UserID      

    DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Connect = SQLConnectString
    DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").SQL = strFilter
    DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Execute dbFailOnError
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Because "@" isn't an integer, but your parameter is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClearWebsitePwd] 
  @userID INT
AS
```

To make it more clear:

- The user enters `@123` in frm.UserID
- The code concatenates `strFilter` & [sp name] & `@123`
- The `IF` statement looks at the first character of frm.UserID, determines that it's an `@`, and continues into the `True` section of code
- The true section passes `@123` as the parameter to the stored procedure
- The stored procedure expects an integer, so it quietly barfs when it gets a string, returning no indication of an error

To fix it:

```
If frm.Tag Then
    If Left(CustomerName, 1) = "@" Then        
        strFilter = strFilter & "sp_ClearWebsitePwd" 
        strFilter = strFilter & ", " & right(frm!UserID, len(frm!UserID) - 1)

        DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Connect = SQLConnectString
        DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").sql = strFilter
    End If  
End If
'assumes something happens here to actually execute the query
```

This will trim the leading `@` from the UserID *before* passing it as an int.

To be honest, I'd suggest you try to find another trigger value to indicate that an account is disabled. Maybe consider adding an 'Active' field (set everyone to True) and using your SP to set that to False, or, conversely, add a 'Disabled' field (set everyone to False) and use your SP to set that field to 'True'.

Comment: Seems OP is concatenating the `UserId` value into the SP call (`strFilter & ", " & frm!UserID`), and that the `@` is part of the `CustomerName` field.

Comment: True, but `frm!UserID` contains `@123` which is why the initial character, `@` can be used as the trigger to get into the `IF` which executes the SP. `@`, is part of the string that is being passed into a SP that is expecting an integer parameter. `@123` is _not_ an integer.

Comment: OK, finally saw what @Mat'sMug was talking about - it's been a long day. Until there's more clarity from OP, this probably won't fix anything.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for trying to help me out. I found out what I was missing out. Everything is correct except I was missing to set `DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").ReturnsRecords = False`
So, the correct version will be:

```vb
Private Sub UserName_AfterUpdate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim strFilter As String

    Dim DB As Database
    Set DB = CodeDb

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUsers", , , , , acDialog
    Set frm = Forms!frmUsers

    If frm.Tag Then
        strFilter = strFilter & "sp_ClearWebsitePwd"
        strFilter = strFilter & ", " & frm!UserID      

        If Left(UserName, 1) = "@" Then        

            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Connect = SQLConnectString
            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").ReturnsRecords = False
            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").sql = strFilter
            DB.QueryDefs("qryClearWebsitePwd").Execute dbFailOnError
        End If  
    End If
End Sub
```

Once I added this line of code, it worked just fine. It seems like SQL was waiting for some return values but access was not returning anything.